# Accessing Field Variable from Generic Object

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection

I have two classes, `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo`, that update a public field `data` i.e.,

```
public class ClassOne {
    public byte[] data = new byte[10];

    // Thread that updates data

}
```

and

```
public class ClassTwo {
    public byte[] data = new byte[10];

    // Thread that updates data

}
```

Only one class and its associated thread is running at any given time, i.e., the app detects the source of the data at run time and uses either `ClassOne` or `ClassTwo`. I want to parse the data in a separate class called `ParseMyData`, but a little confused as to the best way to set this up so `ParseMyData` can access `data` from either `ClassOne` or `ClassTwo`.

I'm currently trying to do it using generics, something like:

```
public class ParseMyData<T> {

    T classOneOrClassTwo;

    ParseMyData(T t) {
        classOneOrClassTwo = t;
    }

    public void parseIt() {
        // Need to access data from either ClassOne or ClassTwo here, something like:
        classOneOrClassTwo.data; // this obviously doesn't work
    }
```

So my question is how do I access the field `data` from within the class `ParseMyData`? Do I have to use reflection? Is reflection the only and best method to use?

New to generics and reflection, so thoughts and pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` could implement an interface which provides an access method. This is probably not a good idea in a threaded program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an interface `DataProvider` with a method `getData()` which returns your `data` field.
Then in your class `ParseMyData<T>` you will write instead `ParseMyData<T extends DataProvider>`.

```
public class ParseMyData<T extends DataProvider> {

    T classOneOrClassTwo;

    ParseMyData(T t) {
        classOneOrClassTwo = t;
    }

    public void parseIt() {
        classOneOrClassTwo.getData();
    }
```

Alternatively you might also use your version, but do an `instanceof` check first and then cast to either `ClassOne` or `ClassTwo`. But I'd recommend you to go with the first option.

Comment: Fantastic. First go at generics this morning, and didn't realise that you can extend it with an interface. Makes sense as you've written - I'll test it and upvote/mark etc. when done. Thnx.