# How to access the field variable of a class through a generic object?

Tags: java, oop, generics, generic-programming, data-members

I've been testing out generic programming in Java.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class Vehicle<T extends Style> {

    private T make;
    private String color;
    private int year;
    private String brand;
    private String model;

    public Vehicle() {
        this.brand = make.getMake();
    }

    public Vehicle(String c, int yr, String mod) {
        this.brand = make.getMake();
        this.color = c;
        this.year = yr;
        this.model = mod;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println(this.year + " " + this.color + " " + this.brand + " " + this.model);
    }

    public void setColor(String c) {
        this.color = c;
    }
    public void setYear(int yr) {
        this.year = yr;
    }
    public void setModel(String mod) {
        this.model = mod;
    }
}
```

And here is the interface `Style` that is being extended in the type parameter:

```
public interface Style {

    public String getMake();
    public boolean usesGas();
    public boolean usesElectricity();

}
```

This interface is implement by another class called `Ford`, where the `getMake()` method is implement like so:

```
private String make = "FORD";

public String getMake() {
    return make;
}
```

In my driver class `Test`, I am testing all of these things like so:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vehicle<Ford> fordFusion = new Vehicle<Ford>();
        fordFusion.setColor("GRAY");
        fordFusion.setModel("FUSION");
        fordFusion.setYear(2015);
        fordFusion.printInfo();
    }
}
```

Now, in my understanding, one should be able to access the field variables and methods of a generic object by using an interface, which in this case is my `Style` interface. And the compiler has no problems with this in the IDE. The program should be accessing the `getMake()` method and printing out:

`2015 GRAY FORD FUSION`

However, the console shows:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Vehicle.<init>(Vehicle.java:32)
at Test.main(Driver.java:16)`

which points to the line where I have `this.brand = make.getMake();`

So what in the world is going on here? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** The question that this has been marked a duplicate of does not give a solution to my particular situation. Although the error here is a `NullPointerException`, it is much different than that older question.

[Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494817/accessing-field-variable-from-generic-object) that address the same issue as mine. If the solution to that question is valid, then I should be able to accomplish what I've been trying to do.

Comment: Hint: what is the value of `make` in your second constructor?

Comment: In the constructors, you haven't assigned any value to `make` yet, so it's null,  so `make.getMake()` doesn't work.

Comment: In all constructors. Nope, generics are not what you think they are.

Comment: Your generics are not needed here. You can simply replace `T` with `Style` and drop the generics part. And that's why you get a null pointer exception.

Comment: But can I even assign a value to `make`? It is of the generic type `T`, so I don't see how I could. Does this mean that what I'm trying to do is impossible? Am I unable to access the field variables and methods of a generic object?

Comment: @AgentBlue: That is completely possible.  Your problem is that you need an _instance_, and, due to type erasure, you can't create one yourself in that class.

Comment: Instead, you should accept an instance as a parameter, at which point you probably don't need generics.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, I see. I had eventually figured out that I would need to create an object of the `Ford` class and then pass through the constructor or a setter method of the generic object, which feels kinda redundant and thus defeats the purpose of generics. Maybe there's a situation where generics actually makes a lot of sense, but in this case it's just kinda silly.